# Get data from Examples table on scenario outline?

Tags: c#, specflow

Does specflow provide a way to get data from the "Examples" table when using the scenario outline format? Similar to how tags are available in scenario context during execution.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way for that.

The examples you write into the examples table are like parameter for a scenario.
These values are replaces the placeholder in your scenario steps (they are in <> brackets)

Example from the Gherkin documentation (https://cucumber.io/docs/reference - Scenario Outline)

```
Scenario Outline: feeding a suckler cow
  Given the cow weighs <weight> kg
  When we calculate the feeding requirements
  Then the energy should be <energy> MJ
  And the protein should be <protein> kg

  Examples:
    | weight | energy | protein |
    |    450 |  26500 |     215 |
    |    500 |  29500 |     245 |
    |    575 |  31500 |     255 |
    |    600 |  37000 |     305 |
```

You can only get the whole table, if you are using a data table as parameter.
Example:

```
Given the following users exist:
  | name   | email              | twitter         |
  | Aslak  | aslak@cucumber.io  | @aslak_hellesoy |
  | Julien | julien@cucumber.io | @jbpros         |
  | Matt   | matt@cucumber.io   | @mattwynne      |
```

You can access this with this binding:

```
[Given(@"the following users exist:")
public void TheFollowinUsersExists(Table table)
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick post! My goal is to use this data in scoped beforeEach block. Open to work around if anyone has any bright ideas.